# Add Comment and Reaction Count in Wordpress with Disqus plugin

Tags: wordpress, comments, disqus

Okay I'm trying to add comments and reactions count just like what you would normally see on some wordpress blogs like http://johntwang.com/blog/ where on the left top of each post there is ** comment  and * reactions*

[image]
<sub>(source: [windows7hacker.com](http://www.windows7hacker.com/wp-content/themes/MPG/images/comments_and_reaction.png))</sub>

My problem is I can't find the disqus's documentation, where hopefully there is some method I can call to return me the number of reactions and comments. Also if I use the [wordpress default method](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/comments_popup_link)

```
<?php comments_popup_link ('zero','one','more','CSSclass','none');?>
```

it only displays "Comments" not even the comment's number count on the main page.

How can I add reaction and comment count with disqus plugin  ?

**edit:**

well my site is http://www.windows7hacker.com/ I don't know how I suppose to add comments count at first place. But right now if I use the wordpress method, it will return me only **comments**, which is exactlly one of the problem they have described in their help page

[image]
<sub>(source: [windows7hacker.com](http://windows7hacker.com/wp-content/uploads/images/comments_count.png))</sub>

I've tired to check the comment count option still doesn't work :(

Comment: anybody? help? I still couldn't figure out how to do that

Answer (score 4):

I've never used the wordpress plugin. But I have used the JS only version.

You can get JS only Disqus working pretty quickly by doing the following.

1. Add this JS to your page.

   `<script type="text/javascript">
   //<![CDATA[
   (function() {
       var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
       var query = '?';
       for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
       if(links[i].href.indexOf('#disqus_thread') >= 0) {
           query += 'url' + i + '=' + encodeURIComponent(links[i].href) + '&';
       }
       }
       document.write('<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="http://disqus.com/forums/ohu/get_num_replies.js' + query + '"></' + 'script>');
   })();
   //]]>
   </script>`
2. Add this code to where you want the comments to display (so probably underneath the post text)

   `<div id="disqus_thread"></div><script type="text/javascript" src="http://disqus.com/forums/ohu/embed.js"></script><noscript><a href="http://disqus.com/forums/ohu/?url=ref">View the discussion thread.</a></noscript><a href="http://disqus.com" class="dsq-brlink">blog comments powered by <span class="logo-disqus">Disqus</span></a>`
3. Finally - to get the comment count to show. All you need to do is append *#disqus_thread* to your permalink URL in any  tag... so for example...

   `<a href="domain.com/article">Comments</a>`

would become...

```
<a href="domain.com/article#disqus_thread">Comments</a>
```

And that will replace "Comments" with x Comments... (x being the number of comments for that post).

I'm a little rusty with wordpress templates so I'm not 100% sure where you would put all of that. But if you have anymore questions I can try to help out.

Comment: Also... you can look on the disqus site here: http://disqus.com/comments/universal/ohu/

It tells you how to set up JS only disqus on a page.

Comment: thanks for the link, it looks like the first answer's JS code. I will give it a try and see how it goes

Comment: What about the "reactions" count, like here: https://blog.disqus.com/reactions-a-new-way-for-readers-to-engage?utm_source=motd_admin&amp;utm_medium=web.

Answer (score 2):

I know there is a wordpress [plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/disqus-comment-system/) for disqus. However if you want to set it up just using plain old js, disqus provides a snippet for you to use in their Universal Instructions page

http://disqus.com/comments/universal/*YOURDISQUSACCOUNT*

This is the comment snippet they provide

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
(function() {
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    var query = '?';
    for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    if(links[i].href.indexOf('#disqus_thread') >= 0) {
        query += 'url' + i + '=' + encodeURIComponent(links[i].href) + '&';
    }
    }
    document.write('<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="http://disqus.com/forums/YOURDISQUSACCOUNT/get_num_replies.js' + query + '"></' + 'script>');
})();
//]]>
</script>
```

The Instructions default page is here http://disqus.com/comments/install/*YOURDISQUSACCOUNT*

This page is actually quite hard to get to...

Comment: thanks. what do i suppose to do with this piece of javascript ? I've add more detail now hope address the problem more clear